# RDBで、あるテーブルを複数条件でフィルタしたい、という際の設計のベスト・プラクティスを知りたい

Tags: mysql, sql, データベース設計

RDBで、あるテーブルを複数条件（AND/OR含む）でフィルタしたい、という際の設計のベスト・プラクティスを知りたいです。

具体的に例を上げると、

```
テーブル名: sample_table
スキーマ: 
 - id integer
 - name varchar
 - condition1 integer,
 - condition2 integer,
  ....,
 - conditionN integer
```

といったカラムを持ったテーブルに対して、

```
select * from sample_table where condition1 = 2 AND condition9 = 1;
select * from sample_table where (condition1 = 1 AND condition3 = 1) OR condition4 = 3;
```

といったSQLを、Nが増えても減っても、
問題なく発行できるような設計を行いたいです。

手がかりすらわからず、もしよろしければどなたかご教授いただけないでしょうか。
宜しくおねがい致します。

Comment: 増えても減ってもというのは上記のSQLを変えずにということですか？例えばカラム`condition9`がないのにそのSQLをエラーなしで発行したい･･･？

Comment: kotatsuさんのコメントにも関連しますが、 「Nが増えても減っても、問題なく」というのは、現状何を問題と感じていて、どうなれば理想状態になると考えているのでしょうか？もしかすると、SQL単体ではなく、それを呼び出すプログラムやフレームワークの処理も含めて回答を考える必要があるかもしれません。そういった話も質問に追記してもらえると、さらに役立つ回答が得られると思います。

Answer (score 2):

2つのテーブルに分割するのが素直な設計ではないでしょうか。

```
CREATE TABLE sample (
  id integer,
  name text
);

CREATE TABLE condition (
  sample_id integer,
  n integer,  -- conditionN
  v integer   -- Value
);
```

```
-- condition1 = 2 AND condition9 = 1
SELECT * FROM sample WHERE id in(
  SELECT sample_id FROM condition WHERE (n,v) = (1,2)
  INTERSECT 
  SELECT sample_id FROM condition WHERE (n,v) = (9,1)
);

-- (condition1 = 1 AND condition3 = 1) OR condition4 = 3
SELECT * FROM sample WHERE id in(
  (SELECT sample_id FROM condition WHERE (n,v) = (1,1)
   INTERSECT 
   SELECT sample_id FROM condition WHERE (n,v) = (3,1))
  UNION
  SELECT sample_id FROM condition WHERE (n,v) = (4,3)
);
```

こうしておけば、DB設計は変えずに`N`をどんどん増やせると思います。

なお、上記SELECT文を http://sqlfiddle.com で確認したところ、PostgreSQL 9.3では動作しましたが、MySQL 5.6では動作しませんでした。`condition`が予約語なのと、`INTERSECT`機能が存在しないことが原因のようです。
タグによるとMySQLを使われているようなので、SELECTの際はご注意ください。

---

検証に使ったデータ

```
INSERT INTO sample VALUES
  (1, 'one')
 ,(2, 'two')
 ,(3, 'three')
 ,(4, 'four')
;
INSERT INTO condition VALUES
  (1, 1,2)
 ,(1, 9,0)
 ,(2, 1,1)
 ,(2, 3,1)
 ,(2, 4,0)
 ,(3, 4,3)
 ,(4, 1,2)
 ,(4, 9,1)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

「設計の」というのが辛いですね。
条件式がANDだったりORだったり()ついてたり複雑過ぎます。
（別テーブルに条件出して…とか考えましたが面倒くさそうです）

残念ながら。私は、こんな情けない方法しか思いつきませんでした。
設計のベストではなく。その設計を前提として、どうやって検索結果を得るかというアプローチになってしまって申し訳ないのですが。

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SAMPLE()
BEGIN
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SELECT NULL FROM DUAL WHERE FALSE;
  SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE <conditions>;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
CALL SAMPLE;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SAMPLE;
```

こうすることでconditionに間違いがあれば
(例：condition9が存在していないのにcondition9が指定されている)
SQLEXCEPTIONをキャッチして、SELECT NULL FROM DUAL WHERE FALSEが実行されます。
SELECT NULL FROM DUAL WHERE FALSEの実行結果は、必ずEmptySetです。

都度プロシージャを作って捨ててを繰り返すので。とっても非エコです。

Answer (score 1):

**「可変長のカラム数を持つテーブルでSQLの条件指定にそのカラムを使いたい」** という質問として回答します。

私の回答はOracleの書き方ですが参考にどうぞ

最初に可変長のカラム数を持つテーブルのカラム名かcount数を取得する。

```
select column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'sample_table' and column_name like 'condition%';
```

これから戻り値を元にプログラムでSQLを組み立てたり分岐すると宜しいかと

動的SQLに組み込んでも良いでしょう。  
http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1297167927  
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/b56260/dynamic.htm#CACDDACH

...  
例のようにconditionNの中身が1桁の整数固定ならテーブルの可変カラムは止めて  
1つのvarchar型カラムにconditionNの中身を順番に入れてしまって文字の位置指定の  
substr等で取り出し/判定をした方が良い気がしますね。

```
select * from sample_table where (condition1 = 1 AND condition3 = 1) OR condition4 = 3;
```

を↓のようにパターンマッチで書けますしregexp_likeで正規表現も使えます。

```
select * from sample_table where condition like '1?1%' or condition like '???3%';
```

Answer (score 0):

### 追記とお詫び

Railsの設計方法だと勘違いしていました。
この回答は無視してください。

---

「手がかりすらわからず」ということなので、Railsのscopeももしかするとご存じないのかな？と思いました。

というわけで一度「scope」という機能を調べてみてください。

ネットを検索するとたくさんのサイトがヒットすると思います。

たとえば以下のサイトで紹介されているコード例なんかは質問の件に近いのではないでしょうか？

http://ruby-rails.hatenadiary.com/entry/20140814/1407994568

> スコープ同士をマージすることにより、where句のAND条件を実現することができます。

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :inactive, -> { where state: 'inactive' }
  scope :finished, -> { where state: 'finished' }
end

# 使用方法
User.inactive.finished
# => SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."state" = 'inactive' AND "users"."state" = 'finished'
```

あと、検索用フォームを作成する場合はRansackというgemを使うと便利です。  
こちらもネットにたくさん情報が載っています。  
参考までにこちらのリンクを紹介しておきます。

http://qiita.com/LuckOfWise/items/e020e896e71d47d0c6a4

「手がかり」はつかめましたでしょうか？  
以上、ご参考までに。

Comment: これはRailsの質問なんでしょうか。DB設計の質問だと思うのですが。

Comment: あ、本当ですね。勘違いしていました。すいません。